# how do i open contacts when i click a button defined in main.xml

Tags: android, button, contacts, buttonclick

I am developing a gps tracking app in android. I am done with displaying the map n stuff. Now I want to make a button on top which when clicked would display the contacts, Then when I select the contact it should show me his or her location.
Please help me with this.
Thank you.

Comment: Pretty sure this is the same question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4992564/open-device-contacts-list-at-button-click-event

Comment: thanks.. but where do i define that code.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9766263/getting-contact-number-using-content-provider-in-android/9883740#9883740 check this would help you

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can set an Event on Button click by setting an `OnClickListener` on the Button with the following code, and use Intent to call ContactPicker activity:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                 Intent intent= new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,  ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);

        startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_CONTACT);

            }
        });
```

and in `onActivityResult()` process the contact uri to load details of contact.

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  super.onActivityResult(reqCode, resultCode, data);

  switch (reqCode) {
    case (PICK_CONTACT) :
      if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        Uri contactData = data.getData();
        Cursor c =  managedQuery(contactData, null, null, null, null);
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
          String name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
          // TODO Fetch other Contact details as you want to use

        }
      }
      break;
  }
}
```

Comment: How can I select multiple contacts?

Comment: What is managedQuery, where did you declare that before using

Answer (score 11):

You should use `startActivityForResult`

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);  
startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

See ["get contact info from android contact picker"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3044545/1430996) for more information.

Comment: +1 for using `ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI` because `Contacts.CONTENT_URI` is deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

try this code

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DEFAULT, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

Use `ACTION_DEFAULT` instead of `ACTION_PICK`.

Good Luck.

Comment: Can you explain in detail ?